# Is Friedberg's proof wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm now reviewing Linear Algebra. As the picture, Theorem 1.3 said that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if

- (a) $0_V\in W$
- (b) $\forall x,~y\in W,~x+y\in W$
- (c) $\forall c\in F,~\forall x\in W,~cx\in W$.

In the "Conversely" part of the proof, if (a), (b), (c) holds, the author want to show that $W$ is a subspace of $V$. However, even if (a), namely $0_V\in W$ holds, we don't know that $0_V$ is the zero vector of $W$. He didn't show this. And this, is not so trivial that can be just said without a proof.

And next, the author went to prove that every element in $W$ has an inverse. He said that, by (c), we know that $(-1)v\in W$, and on the other hand, $(-1)v=-v\in W$. Here arises a critical question, what does this $-v$ corresponding to? Is it:

- corresponding to $V$. i.e., $v+(-v)=0_V=(-v)+v$?
- or corresponding to $W$. i.e., admit that $0_W$ exists, and at the same time $v+(-v)=0_W=(-v)+v$?

By the context, it should be corresponding to $V$, namely $-v_V$. And then, the author must have to show that this $-v_V$, is the inverse element with respect to $W$. And this, again, is not so trivial that can even be stated without some arguments. I think Friedberg mistaken the role of $0$ and $-v$ here, leading he omitted some key part in the proof. Do you agree? If the proof of this theorem is a part of a mid-term exam for undergraduate students, and if a student write the proof just in that way, I think there would be few points.

[image]

Updated: (the page before this theorem)
[image]

Comment: In the "conversely" part, we are proving that $W$ is a subspace. The point is that, to prove $W$ is a vector space in this case, we define $0_W$ to be $0_V$ - we do not already know $W$ is a subspace yet, so we don't already have an element $0_W$.

Comment: It might also help if you include the "discussion preceding this theorem" that the author refers to in the proof.

Comment: @CarlMummert Updated. I agree with your opinion. But I think the author should say that $\forall v\in W,~v+0_V=v=0_V+v$; or at least say that $0_V$ is the identity for $W$(the author only said $0_V\in W$, and nothing). But the more crucial part is the "inverse element" part, if we have not said $0_V$ is the identity for $W$, by knowing that $v+(-v)=0_V=(-v)+v$ doesn't mean that $-v$ is the inverse of $v$ with respect to $W$.

Comment: Just above Theorem 1.3, the author says "the next theorem shows that the zero vector of $W$ must be the same as the zero vector of $V$". So I think they did say that $0_V$ will be the identity for $W$, if that vector is in $W$.  Separately, the inverse is defined entirely by vector addition, so really there is no freedom to choose a different inverse operation for $W$, because $W$ is using the same addition operation as $V$.  (This doesn't matter for the proof, but any inverse in $W$ is also an inverse in $V$.)

Comment: Yeah, I think the sentence you cited, is the "non-conversely" part in the proof, namely the paragraph before the word "Conversely." In that paragraph, that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ is the hypothesis, and the author was going to show that $0_W=0_V$(by using the cancellation law). However, in the "conversely" part, this fact can not directly be taken to use, because this time the background hypothesis are changed.

Comment: If we already know that, in order for $W$ to be a subspace, it is necessary for $0_W$ to be $0_V$, and then we move to the "conversely" part, the only choice we could possibly make to identify $0_W$ is to identify it as $0_V$.  While it would be possible for the author to stress this, I think it is clear enough from the overall discussion. The author said explicitly before the theorem that the zero vector of $V$ must be the same as the zero vector of $W$.  All that is left in the "conversely" is to show that, under that assumption and conditions (a), (b), and (c) that $W$ is a vector space.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it *is* obvious that $0_V$ must be the  zero vector of $W$. It satisfies $0+v=v$ for all elements in $v\in V$, and in particular those in $W$. There can only be one element with that property, of course.

The same can be said about the additive inverse of any element of $W$. If you agree that $v$ has an additive inverse "in $W$", then you must immediately see why it is the same as the one "in $V$."

Everything seems totally clear as written, IMO.

Comment: "If you agree that vv has an additive inverse in $W$", do you mean $-v_V$ or $-v_W$?

Comment: Actually, rereading it the author did a very clear job explaining why the two identities coincide. If there's a partial vulgar line you think is false you will need to get more specific.

Comment: What does the "two identities" you refer to?

Comment: @Eric: are you asking about the "conversely" part still? There we are proving $W$ is a subspace, so we have to define $-v_W$ ourselves. Of course we define it to be $-v_V$.

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes.

Comment: @Eric I do not understand where you are stuck. Let $w\in W$. By hypothesis, $(-1)w\in W$. This is an additive inverse of $w$ in $W$, in fact, *the unique* additive inverse in all of $V$.  I don't know what you want to say with "$-v_V$".

Comment: How do you know that $(-1)w$ is equals to $-w$, where $-w$ means the additive inverse with respect to $W$?

Comment: @Eric Because $-w$ is the **unique** $x$ with the property that $w+x=0$.  $(-1)w$ does that, so it is precisely $-w$.

Answer (score 1):

In the "conversely" part of the proof, we assume conditions (a), (b), and (c) and have to show that $W$ is a vector space with the addition and scalar multiplication inherited from $V$.

To prove $W$ is a vector space, we have to show that there is a vector $z \in W$ that is an additive identity for vector addition. By condition (a), $0_V$ is in $W$, and by the "prior discussion" this is a zero vector for $W$.  In the "conversely" part we are not assuming that $W$ is a vector space, and so there is not a pre-existing $0_W$ that we could refer to.

Moreover, as the author points out just before the theorem statement, it follows from the first part of the proof that the only option for the zero vector of a subspace $W$ is the zero vector of $V$. So, in the second part, when we are trying to prove that $W$ is a subspace, we had better take the zero vector of $W$ to be the zero vector of $V$!

Similarly, to show that each vector in $W$ has an additive inverse in $W$, if $u \in W$ then $-u \in V$ and so $-u = (-1)w$ is in $W$ by condition (c).  Also $u + -u = 0$ because this was already true in $V$ and $W$ has the same addition for vectors in $W$.

Because we do not yet know $W$ is a vector space, we can't assume that there is a pre-existing additive inverse operation in $W$. Instead, we prove that the restriction of the additive inverse relation on $V$ is an additive inverse relation on $W$.

Comment: We both agree that, "if $W$ is a subspace of $V$, then the identity of $W$ must be the same of the identity of $V$". Now, **in order to prove** that an arbitrary subset $W$ of $V$ satisfying conditions (a), (b) and (c), is a subspace, the only candidate for the identity of $W$ is $0_V$, so we choose $0_V$ to be $W$'s identity. I think it is a logical problem here.

Comment: Logically speaking, there may be chance that $0_V\in W$ is not the identity for $W$(by the hindsight, we actually know then $W$ is impossible to be a subspace), but we cannot for the sake of deducing $W$ is a subspace, then force ourself believing that $0_V$ is the identity for $W$. Why not just letting $0_V$ to not be the identity for $W$? (and consequently, of course, we no longer hope to deduce $W$'s being a subspace).

Comment: Therefore, if we want to prove the "conversely part", we can have the hindsight in mind that $0_V$ "should" be the identity for $W$, but we ought to explicitly, and indeed, prove that $W$'s identity is $0_V$(aka. $W$ satisfys the one of the vector space axioms), and then keep going to make effort on showing $W$ is a subspace(i.e., also satisfies other axioms).

Comment: @Eric You are apparently making this way too complicated. "Logically speaking, there may be a chance that $0_V$ is not the identity for $W$." This doubt should be very short-lived. $0_V+v=v$ for *every $v\in V$* and $W$ **is a subset of $V$** so it *does* act like an identity, and is therefore the *only* identity.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, I mean so the author should write down this.

Comment: @Eric According to the picture you posted, the author apparently *has* written it down. Did you go look at Theorem 1.2 or not?

Comment: In theorem 1.2, the 3rd and 4th point said that $W$ has a zero vector **with respect to $W$** (not $V$!); and every vector in $W$ has an additive inverse in $W$ **with respect to $W$** (not $V$!). This has nothing to do with our discussion, right?

Comment: Actually, I think the reason the author chose not to write down this, is not he is lazy or saving the space of the page, but rather he think the argument is enough valid, namely he though that by (i)$0_V\in W$ and (ii)"if $W$ is a subspace of $V$, then $W$'s identity is the same of $V$'s identity", it is directly guarantee that $0_V$ is the identity for $W$.